# How do I make a link that goes nowhere?

Tags: html, hyperlink

Is it possible to make a link that does nothing?

I want the item to be a link so I get the cursor to change on mouseover, but I don't want the link to actually go anywhere as it actually triggers the showing of a div with extra functionality on the same page.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Will add to the browser history:

`<a href="#"></a>`

Won't add to the browser history (preferred method):

`<a href="javascript:;"></a>`

Comment: Is this ok even if they have javascript turned off?

Comment: Yes, it will do nothing.

Comment: Just as a note, the latter does cause issues if you have an onclick function set.

Comment: Another note: `href="javascript:;"` is not, and has never been, the preferred method. Placing JS code in a HTML attribute should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: This navigates to the page top, though

Answer (score 20):

In my opinion, the most complete hack free solution is:

```
<a href="" onclick="return false;">do absolutely nothing</a>
```

Comment: This solution seems to work the best for me, so far, since I want to use a JavaScript function in `onclick` (I just return false after it): e.g. `<a href="" onclick="myFunction(); return false">my text</a>`

Answer (score 18):

Instead, you could use a `<span>` and set the cursor style:

```
<span id="node42" class="node-link">My Text</span>
```

And specify the cursor in your stylesheet:

```
.node-link { cursor: pointer; }
```

This would also allow you to attach to the node for your actions later (show here using [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/)):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('node42').observe('click', function(event) {
      alert('my click handler');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Roger: using `id` allows the element to be uniquely identified, mostly useful for the javascript example in this case.  You have a good point for the cursor.  It is probably more of a class-based style.  I've updated my answer.  Thanks!

Comment: This won't import the styling of hyper-links (like hyperlink colours, text-decoration...etc). Thus powers1's answer is better.

Comment: This will be bad for accessibility, due to lack of ARIA attributes or anything at all that will tell screen readers that this is an interactive element. It is not even accessible by tab navigation (pressing `Tab` key multiple times).

Answer (score 7):

Just add the style `cursor:pointer` to the element:

```
<a id="clickme">Click Me</a>
```

CSS:

```
#clickme { cursor: pointer }
```

Or (heaven forbid) in-line:

```
<a style="cursor:pointer">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: You must have to use href="#". <a id="clickme">Click Me</a>
will create problem.

Comment: @Umesh, what problem? The only "problem" is that hover styles won't work in IE6 and the `cursor: pointer` won't automatically be applied. Please explain.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two *classic JavaScript* approaches that **won't give you an error** in your **JavaScript console** and/or *don't change the URL nor save it to your browser history:*

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Click on this JavaScript error-free link that won't change your URL nor save it into your browser history</a><hr />
<a href="#void">Maybe a more readable approach, but unfortunately this one changes your URL</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want style, set the the CSS [cursor property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ui.html#propdef-cursor) to pointer.

But it sounds like you want `<a href="javascript:void(do_something())">`.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something simpler, and I think I found it. Do you want your link not to go anywhere? Omit the `href`.

`<a class='irrelevant_for_this_example'>Some text</a>`

`href="#"` will scroll to the top of the page.

`href="javascript:;"` seems dodgy.

A JavaScript solution seems unnecessary for something as simple.

Comment: Actually, I think the OP was probably using the link to trigger a collapsible/expandable box in JavaScript. I can confirm `href="javascript:;"` works for that. Removing the `href` means the browser doesn't treat it as a normal link, i.e., the mouse doesn't change to a finger when you hover over the link.

Comment: Having said that, `href="#void"`, or something like that, works, and may be better