# Remove href values from url

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

```
<a href="#get1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm">GET</button></a>
```

So I have a number of these anchors on multiple pages. They don't link to another page just scroll the user to the section with the same ID.

When clicked it adds '#get1' to the url, is there anyway to remove/disable this feature?

Comment: *"When clicked it adds '#get1' to the url"* - What exactly adds this tag?

Comment: share your full code

Comment: Remove `href="#get1"` maybe ?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp
Link to an element with a specified id within the page (like href="#top")
It's part of what using this type of href does. So you can link to an ID in your page.

Comment: @kchason thank you, I must have missed that will have a look now

Comment: @BadMiscuit, then the scroll wouldn't work... also, Kyle, I don't know the application, but sometimes there is a benefit to having the URL be able to be called with the anchor

Comment: this should remove the hrefs: `document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\s+href\s*=\s*(?:(?:\")|(?:\')).*?(?:(?:\")|(?:\'))/gi,"");`

Comment: @KobyDouek that's what an anchor does.

Comment: @freedomn-m Of course, I was leading the OP to understand what he's asking

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1830934/4411297
Depend's on if you want the links to take you to another section or not.
You could also override the onclick() event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, by hijacking it with jQuery (or plain JS, but you have a jQuery tag). On the click you prevent the actual event (so the anchor never works like a default anchor, eg: dont change location) and then do any [scroll actions with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047454/jquery-animate-scroll).

```
$('.example').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const elem = this; // save it so we can use it in the animate

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(elem).attr('href') ).offset().top
     }, 2000);
});
```

*In my example, I'm assuming that you have "#example" in the href, and a matching ID. If you want more complex selections, you should change the `attr('href')` part to eg a `data()` attribute*